# Converting List to pandas DataFrame

Tags: list, pandas, dataframe

I need to build a DataFrame with a very specific structure. Yield curve values as the data, a single date as the index, and days to maturity as the column names.

```
In[1]: yield_data  # list of size 38, with yield values
Out[1]: 
[0.096651956137087325,
 0.0927199778042056,
 0.090000225505577847,
 0.088300016028163508,...


In[2]: maturity_data  # list of size 38, with days until maturity
Out[2]:
[6,
 29,
 49,
 70,...

In[3]: today
Out[3]: 
Timestamp('2017-07-24 00:00:00')
```

Then I try to create the DataFrame

```
pd.DataFrame(data=yield_data, index=[today], columns=maturity_data)
```

but it returns the error

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 38), indices imply (38, 1)
```

I tried using the transpose of these lists, but it does not allow to transpose them.

how can I create this DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, I think you want a dataframe with a single row, you need to reshape your data input list into a list of list.

```
yield_data = [0.09,0.092, 0.091]
maturity_data = [6,10,15]
today = pd.to_datetime('2017-07-25')

pd.DataFrame(data=[yield_data],index=[today],columns=maturity_data)
```

Output:

```
              6      10     15
2017-07-25  0.09  0.092  0.091
```